# How to get selected item in react-native-modal-selector

Tags: react-native

`react-native-modal-selector` has the `getSelectedItem()`(for 
 getting the currently selected item) but when I'm using this method it's not working, it's not giving me any selected item.

code:

```
<ModalSelector
                                selectStyle={{ borderWidth: 0 }}
                                selectTextStyle={{ color: '#ffffff' }}
                                data={this.filterData()}
                                visible={this.state.visible}
                                optionTextStyle={{ fontSize: 20 }}
                                labelExtractor={(item) => item.categoryName}
                                initValue="Choose Category"
                                supportedOrientations={[ 'landscape' ]}
                                accessible={true}
                                getSelectedItem={(item)=> console.log(item)}
                                keyExtractor={(item) => item.categoryId}
                                closeOnChange={false}
                                backdropPressToClose={true}

         />
```

Answer (score 0):

Get currently selected value of from array using the below code.

```
<ModalSelector
     data={data}
     initValue="Select something yummy!"
     supportedOrientations={['landscape']}
     accessible={true}
     scrollViewAccessibilityLabel={'Scrollable options'}
     cancelButtonAccessibilityLabel={'Cancel Button'}
     onChange={(option)=>{ this.setState({textInputValue:option.label})}}>
```

**getSelectedItem()**: get current selected item, updated by **onChange()** event only.
so that's the reason you are not getting currently selected value.
Hope it helps to you.